# Ways creatures evolove

Tags: natural-selection

I can't find the right answers to my questions online .

are there other ways creatures evolove apart form nsatural selection?

Thank you

Comment: Artificial selection, to name one

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are a number of processes that affect evolution of populations.

The classification of these processes can be open to some philosophical discussion. For example, most authors, don't really consider natural and artificial selection as being different. Also, most authors tend to consider sexual selection as being a subset of natural selection. At the end of the day, the details classification does not really matter to science as long as we have clearly defined (mathematical) models of these processes. I will just list concepts below ignoring potential issue of classification:

- Natural selection
- Artificial selection
- Sexual selection
- Genetic drift (incl. population bottleneck and other demographic elements)
- Gene flow, interbreeding and hybridization
- Linked selection (genetic hitchhiking, background selection)

For more information about what evolution is and what are the processes that affect evolution of populations, you might want to have a look at a short very introductory course to evolutionary biology such as for example [**evo101**](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01) by UC Berkeley.